# Permissions on Orchard Layout Elements

Tags: orchardcms

We are using Orchard Layouts in order to allow content writers to write articles made up of re-usable components.

They are able to select the components for a particular page and the order that they appear in.

However, we don't want them to be able to change the overall layout, such as adding or changing columns or rows (anything under the layout category in the toolbox), we just want them to be able to place elements in the layout that we have provided.

Is is possible to control this through permissions? Or is there another approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not through permissions alone, but you can separate the layout design in a `Layout Blueprint`, and then use that blueprint for the pages in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide elements with CSS. You have to load a specific CSS file e.g **noadmin.css** only when the user is not admin. For example add this code in the the **Layout.cshtml** file in the **Views** folder of **TheAdmin Theme**:

```
@{
    if(!AuthorizedFor(Orchard.Security.StandardPermissions.SiteOwner)) {
        Style.Include("noadmin.css").AtHead();
    }
}
```

You can find the CSS in [this](https://github.com/georgeroubie/Hide-Elements-from-Layout-Part-Orchard-CMS) repository.
You can also read [this](https://orchardtricks.dotnest.com/blog/hide-elements-from-layout-part-orchard-cms) article.